# Make Bootstrap columns stack to form a Windows Title Style Design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

His is what I am looking to achieve:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   item 1  |  itme 2   | item 3    |
| .col-md-4 | .col-md-4 | .col-md-4 |
|           |           +-----------+
+-----------+           | item 6    |
|           |           | .col-md-4 |
|  item 4   +-----------+           |
| .col-md-4 | .col-md-4 |           |
|           | item 5    +-----------+
+-----------+           |
            |           |
            +-----------+
```

How would I be able to make this happen using css? I don't want to columns to appear on the next line to the bottom of the heightest .col-md-4 div on the previous row.

I need the divs to fill up the spaces so that they stick to each other without leaving spaces in between each row.

Something like this but that scales properly on different devices: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mIkhq

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: you may find this useful `http://masonry.desandro.com/`. or `http://salvattore.com/`

Comment: I think I will be able to figure it out with the article: http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use nested columns and rows... kinda like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that the way I generate the columns means they are in date order and if I do this on phone, when the website is scaled, they will no longer appear in the correct order.

Comment: @Pabi -- probably best to show and hide two different layouts based on breakpoints. Or, don't use Bootstrap grid and use Flexbox.

Comment: Hmm, let me know what is the order supposed to be (preferably a picture). I am not sure which is supposed to be what.

Comment: @Elvanos Edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are Jquery plugins that do it, for example [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).